# Can I use XPath expressions instead of CSS selectors on page.type in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, css-selectors, puppeteer

The code now:

```
await page.type('#filterdataTable > div.widget > input', "1234");
```

Can I use XPath instead of this CSS Selector?

Comment: Did you try `page.$x("//something_here");`?

Comment: Yes... but not work for .type method.

Comment: select the element, then use the .type function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) to obtain the [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) of the element you want to select.

Then you can use [`elementHandle.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options) to type text into the `input` field.

```js
const example = await page.$x('//*[@id="filterdataTable"]/div[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " widget ")]/input');
await example[0].type('1234');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
const [selector] = await scope.context.currentPage.$x(path);
await scope.context.currentPage.evaluate(
    (element, value) => element.value = value, selector, text);
```

where `xpath` is he XML path and `text` holds the characters you want to type.